# Spring MVC Servlet being hit twice for a POST request

Tags: rest, tomcat, spring-mvc, servlets

I've got an estrange issue while using Spring MVC in order to implement RESTful services for my web application. Everything seems to work OK while performing GET requests, however, the behaviour I'm dealing with when doing POST requests puzzles me. Well, I've implemented this very basic controller code:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/services")
public class RestService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void postTest(@RequestBody String postString)
            throws PersistenceException {
        System.out.println(postString);
    }

}
```

When I perform a POST request against it using Curl:

```
curl --data "Hello world" http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC-REST/services/test/post
```

First time my Controller is reached properly and the String is displayed. However, don't know why, **the [Spring MVC servlet](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet.html) is being called again** after that, in this case with a wrong url request. The framework is not finding the matching service case, obviously:

> Jun 02, 2014 4:06:21 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
>   WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC-REST/services/test/services/test/post] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Debugger's stack seems to be slightly different for the first and second cases:

[image: First case]

[image: Second case]

It seems like second time the Spring MVC framework is trying to render the output, even I'm not interested in it, cause I'm not accesing it via web UI. The servlet configuration I use is the standard one:

```xml
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Spring MVC REST</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
                </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

That happens to me with Tomcat 6 and 7 and spring-web 3.2.8.RELEASE. Can anybody see the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `@ResponseBody` before method return type..it should solve your problem.

so it should be like

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/services")
public class RestService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void postTest(@RequestBody String postString)
            throws PersistenceException {
        System.out.println(postString);
    }

}
```